# how to change url in code igniter within a class

Tags: codeigniter

Hey guys here is the problem i am facing i have a User class which has two functions one login

```
www.abc.com/user/login
```

second the confirm_login

```
www.abc.com/user/confirm_login
```

now i want two things one when i go to confirm_login from login function as

```
 $this->confirm_login();
```

URL does not changes, i want the URL to be as www.abc.com/home and also if some how i push refresh the page, url should keep me on the home page www.abc.com/home. Best Regards

Comment: should i make separate classes for both of these functions?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking? Is your `User` class a controller or model?

Comment: oh sorry about that User is a class

Comment: @theGame you still didn't answer Stephen's question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
redirect('/user/confirm_login/');
```

at the end of the function after it does the login processing.